# object has no attribute '__getitem__' on Django raw query JOIN

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I a running the following query

```
release_list = Releases.objects.raw('SELECT releases.*, COUNT(charts_extended.release_id) as cnt FROM releases INNER JOIN charts_extended ON charts_extended.release_id=releases.id WHERE releases.id=%s',[release_id])
```

which is returning the following error

```
'Releases' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

My models are as follows

```
class Releases(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    all_artists = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    format = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    label_no_country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.TextField()
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'releases'

class ChartsExtended(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    url = models.TextField()
    release_id = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'charts_extended'
```

The error only started after I swapped to a Raw query (as I needed to use an inner join)

Previously I was using the following with no error

```
release_list = Releases.objects.filter(id=release_id).values('all_artists','label_no_country','id','title','genre')
```

Comment: Can I ask why you have a `release_id` instead of a foreign key to releases?

Comment: Historical and badly designed database :) would this be stopping the query from working?

Comment: It would make it lots simpler if it did have an fk... `ChartsExtended.objects.filter(release=release).select_related('release')`

Comment: you also added the "count()" to the query, which looks really odd to me.  I'd bet that's the source of your issues.